# How can we delete large partitions (wide rows) based on partition key in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cql, datastax-enterprise

We want to determine the token range containing the wide rows/large partitions and remove the large partition . We are not able to get a way to do this . What we followed is :

1.Find the partition key from the logs

2.We will then check to see which node the key exists on with nodetool  getendpoints --   key

3. Now we have to retrieve the record from SSTable . There are two steps for this :
   a. Find which SSTable the key is located :
       nodetool getsstables --   key

   b. Export the sstable to json format to view problematic keys :
       bin/sstable2json SSTABLE [-k KEY [-k KEY [... ]]]] [-x KEY [-x KEY [... ]]] [-e ]

After importing huge json  data , we are stuck to find the token ranges to be considered large partition/wide row.

we are using DSE 4.5.1 .
Let me know if there is any alternative . Thanks!

Comment: if you know partition key then you can do `DELETE from table where column='partition key'`

Comment: @undefined_variableyou should add your comment as an answer because it is (imo) the correct way to do this :-)